# Adding <a href="#"> to slide images in ReduxFramework

Tags: php, wordpress

Slides are working perfect but I've been trying to add `<a href="#">` to the images with `['url']` and it's not working. Can't see what I'm doing wrong:

```
<?php global $redux_demo;
        foreach($redux_demo['slides'] as $slide) {
            echo '<img src="' . $slide['image'] . '">'; 
        }
 ?>
```

Any help? Thanks.

------------------------------ EDIT ----------------------------------

This is what I have now:

```
  <?php global $redux_demo;
        foreach($redux_demo['slides'] as $slide) {
            if(isset($slide['url'])) {
                 echo '<a href="'.$slide['url'].'">';
            }
            echo '<img src="' . $slide['image'] . '">'; 
            if(isset($slide['url'])) {
                 echo '</a>';
            }
        }
  ?>
```

This is all I'm trying to achieve `<a href='#'><img src='img/image.jpg' /></a>` to link it to a page. It's working fine, I have no errors but the `html` it is not showing the `<a href='#'>`.

Comment: Get an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: are you sure `$redux_demo['slides']` exists and is an array? anple please put the full error message in the question

Comment: `$redux_demo['slides']` exists. As I said, the slides are working fine. On this plugin you use `['url']` as a 'placeholder for the URL field' but I can't see an example anywhere. http://docs.reduxframework.com/redux-framework/fields/slides/

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of var_dump($redux_demo['slides'])?